# Javascript ServiceStack Client serialization error

Tags: javascript, servicestack, aurelia

So I have a master/detail scenario between two views.  The master page shows a list and after clicking on one of the items, I send a message via the EventAggregator in Aurelia to the child view with a deserialized dto (coming from the selected item of the master) as a payload of the message.

However when I then try to pass this item as a parameter of a subsequent request in the child (to get additional info) the payload object fails to serialize.

Master.ts:

```
import { JsonServiceClient } from "servicestack-client";
import {
    ListPendingHoldingsFiles,
    ListPendingHoldingsFilesResponse,
    SendHoldings,
    PositionFileInfo
} from "../holdingsManager.dtos";
import { inject, singleton } from "aurelia-framework";
import { Router } from "aurelia-router";
import { EventAggregator } from "aurelia-event-aggregator";
import { GetPendingPositionMessage } from "../common/GetPendingPositionMessage";

@singleton()
@inject(Router, EventAggregator)
export class Pending {
    router: Router;
    positions: PositionFileInfo[];
    client: JsonServiceClient;
    eventAgg: EventAggregator;

    constructor(router, eventAggregator) {
        this.router = router;
        this.eventAgg = eventAggregator;
        this.client = new JsonServiceClient('/');
        var req = new ListPendingHoldingsFiles();
        this.client.get(req).then((getHoldingsResponse) => {
            this.positions = getHoldingsResponse.PositionFiles;
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e); // "oh, no!"
        });
    }

    openHoldings(positionInfo) {
        this.eventAgg.publish(new GetPendingPositionMessage(positionInfo));
        this.router.navigate('#/holdings');
    }
}
```

Child.ts:

```
import { JsonServiceClient } from "servicestack-client";
import { inject, singleton } from "aurelia-framework";
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';
import { EventAggregator } from "aurelia-event-aggregator";
import { GetPendingPositionMessage } from "../common/GetPendingPositionMessage";
import {
    GetPendingHoldingsFile,
    GetPendingHoldingsFileResponse,
    Position,
    PositionFileInfo
} from "../holdingsManager.dtos";

@singleton()
@inject(Router, EventAggregator)
export class Holdings {
    router: Router;
    pendingPositionFileInfo: PositionFileInfo;
    position: Position;
    client: JsonServiceClient;
    eventAgg: EventAggregator;

    constructor(router, eventAggregator) {
        this.router = router;
        this.eventAgg = eventAggregator;
        this.eventAgg.subscribe(GetPendingPositionMessage,
            message => {
                this.pendingPositionFileInfo = message.fileInfo;
            });
    }

    activate(params, routeData) {
        this.client = new JsonServiceClient('/');
        var req = new GetPendingHoldingsFile();
        req.PositionToRetrieve = this.pendingPositionFileInfo;
        this.client.get(req).then((getHoldingsResponse) => {
            this.position = getHoldingsResponse.PendingPosition;
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e); // "oh, no!"
        });
    }
}
```

So the error happens when the child activates and attempts to send the request 'GetPendingHoldingsFile'.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (NullReferenceException)
```

I have verified that this.pendingPositionFileInfo in the child is not null or empty and that on the server side, the object is not being received (it is null).  I am new to Aurelia and not very experienced with Javascript so I must be missing something, any advice would be appreciated.

**Edit 1**

This seems to be something wrong with how I'm interacting with ServiceStack.  I'm using version 4.5.6 of serviceStack with servicestack-client@^0.0.17.  I tried newing up a fresh copy of the dto (PositionFileInfo) and copying over all the values from the parent view just to be sure there wasn't some javascript type conversion weirdness happening that I'm not aware of, but even with a fresh dto  the webservice still receives a null request.

Comment: Don't use Event Aggregator here... Too complex and redundant with the router. Just save the current record `this.positionInfo = positionInfo;`, then route to your child and have your child import/inject the parent and get the current record.

Comment: Several good demos of similar case here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260833/aurelia-how-can-i-modify-sidebar-content-from-inside-a-router-view

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately this does not resolve the serialization issue.

Comment: Would you still recommend this solution if there are two or more possible 'parents' of the child?  Seems like the constructor would get littered with possible parent viewmodels being injected.

Comment: @LStarky I decided to use a StateStore object as described here, it will be cleaner than both the solution I have above and injecting the parent into the child: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283089/pass-data-to-not-yet-loaded-view-in-aurelia/42284535?noredirect=1#comment71730491_42284535

Answer (score 1):

Switching from 'client.get(...)' to 'client.post(...)' fixed the problem.  Apparently trying to serialize the object over in the URL was not a good plan.

Comment: Definitely a better plan!  I hadn't noticed that in your code, but you're exactly right.